# PageRedirect to previous Page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page(A) that has a popup. When the link in the popup is clicked, it takes you to page B. Page B has a Submit and cancel button. Cancel button should get me back to Page A. How is it possible with javascript or Asp.net??

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button name="cancel" onclick="history.go(-1)">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `history` object to navigate backwards:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="history.back()">
```

This has the same effect as if the user clicked the back button on their browser.